# Taking in a TypeDef as a parameter in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a situation where I'm declaring multiple related `typedef enums` in my constants file:

```
typedef enum 
{
    AnimalTypeBear,
    AnimalTypeBunny,
    MemeTypeCount
} 
AnimalType;

typedef enum 
{
    FishTypeSalmon,
    FishTypeTrout,
    FishTypeCount
} 
FishType;
```

Now I'd like to define a parameter for an initializer called `type` that can take in both of these `typedef enums` as a parameter. I'm currently defining type as an `NSUInteger` and I keep getting 0 no matter which type I send into the initializer (ie FishTypeTrout should be 1 but it is 0). What type of object should `type` be to work for both `enter code here`typeDef enums?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain what you're asking, but I tried the following code:

```
typedef enum AnimalType : NSUInteger
{
    AnimalTypeBear,
    AnimalTypeBunny,
    MemeTypeCount
} AnimalType;


typedef enum FishType : NSUInteger
{
    FishTypeSalmon,
    FishTypeTrout,
    FishTypeCount
} FishType;


void TestFunction(NSUInteger at)
{
    printf("at = %d\n",at);
}
```

and it prints 1 when I call `TestFunction(FishTypeTrout);`

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for doing that. The bug was else where.